# File format/interface for home-brew engines (and implementation in lichess)

Tags: engines, programming, lichess

I'm a hobbyist chess programmer. I've built a few engines from scratch, had lots of fun, and am generally pretty proud of what I've made (I estimate ~1400-1500 though it's hard to tell).

I was very excited when I found out you can make a bot account on lichess. After a few hours of messing around, I successfully played a game against Stockfish running on my computer through the lichess interface, so I think I (sort of) know how to connect an engine to my bot account.

However, for all the engines I've made in the past, I have made my own board representation and move in/output. Obviously I'll need to make some modifications to them in order to connect them to lichess. When connecting Stockfish to my account, I used the Stockfish .exe file you can download online. The lichess interface accepted it, so I'm guessing there's some semi-standard way to make interface with engines. I would like to make one of these interfaces.

Questions: am I correct that there is a standard way to interface with an engine? If so, how would you go about making one? Are there any good guides to doing so?

Or perhaps more generally: how would you adapt a "from scratch" engine to play on lichess?

---

I'm almost entirely self taught programming wise, and am very conscious of the gaping holes in my understanding of computers/programming. Pointing me to any resources would be very helpful.

Comment: FICS [Free Internet Chess Server] also allows a declared engine BOT account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty resources available. First of all, you may be interested in the [Universal Chess Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Chess_Interface) protocol. This is a text protocol that many engines use. A compiled list is available [here](http://www.sdchess.ru/Engines_UCI_top.htm).

The protocol specification is available for download [here](https://www.shredderchess.com/download.html) (last link on the page).
There is also a [python implementation](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io) of the protocol.

Last but not least, there exists a [lichess API implementation in Python](https://python-lichess.readthedocs.io), so you could talk to lichess directly.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to connect a chess engine to anything is the [UCI - the universal chess interface.](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html)

It specifies how the output (and input) of an engine should be structured to be understood by an UI or any other interface.

Answer (score 2):

https://lichess.org/team/lichess-bots has the documentation you are looking for. If you just want the gui you can embed it like in the project used by http://lichess.bitplan.com. If you want to do moves it depends on the programming language you are using. For python e.g. there are ready to use libraries:

- https://github.com/rhgrant10/berserk
- https://github.com/ShailChoksi/lichess-bot

As a committer of [Play Chess With a WebCam](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/play-chess-with-a-webcam) i'll also point you to the implementation within this project see: [lichess.py](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/play-chess-with-a-webcam/blob/master/pcwawc/lichess.py) and the tests for it [test_lichess.py](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/play-chess-with-a-webcam/blob/master/tests/test_lichess.py)